# how to set z-index for before content in translucent item

Tags: css

I have some translucent item blocks and I would like show content behind the translucent item block. This is my html code:

```css
.item{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(1,255,0,0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.item:after{
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: -10px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

In this code z-index working only for next item blok but for self parent block not worked. So how to set z-index for self parent too?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/gbre2Lht/9/)

Answer (score -1):

A simple work-around is that you can set the background image of your translucent html element, like so:

```
.items{
  background-image: IMAGE_LINK
}
```

Hope that helped.